# iOS bar button - How do you place your only cancel (close) bar button?

Tags: ios

If we have 2 bar buttons, we follow the common UX pattern, by placing the **cancel** button on left, and **done** button on right (img#1).

| [image] | [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Img#1 | Img#2 | Img#3 |
|  | **Cancel** button on left | X" icon button on the right |

However, what about a single cancel bar button? (img#2)

Some popular app like WhatsApp, Bear are using such an approach, on some of their pages (img#3)

---

Which do you think is a better design, as far as UX is concerned?

1. A "cancel" button on the left
2. "X" icon button on the right
3. "X" icon button on the left?

Comment: Best to keep your design consistent

Answer (score 0):

First of all personally I would say as a user I would not prefer a send option at the top right. I do not know about which application uses them but think as a user, my focal area is at the middle of the screen and then once I am done with my work, you are asking me to look for how to complete my task by scrolling my eyeballs all over the screen. As a english reader we read from left to right so ideally any action item post task/work should come after the task . Here it should be after the middle section.

Besides that a cross on top right is still ok as users know that as a common place holder and by default they will click on top right either a cross or cancel/hide etc to get out of the bottom sheet.

Comment: But, if you look at major email clients like Gmail, Yahoo! Mail, ... in iOS platform, the send button is at the top right corner.

Comment: Sure they do, but remember they started with desktop version and then was forced down to adapt to mobile. If we go by mobile first, we should see the ease with which we can operate

Comment: I think a good reason to move the Send button to the top is that the bottom side is prone to mis-clicking or palm-clicking. Sending an e-mail can be a nervous affair for certain activities/characters, so the added security is best.